# ubuntu 12.04 Black Screen before login (AMD HD 6470M)

Tags: 12.04

I am using a laptop with the current specification:

AMD Radeon HD 6470M
Intel Core I5-2520m
8GB RAM

Im Using Ubuntu 12.04, I boot into it using the standard Grub loader, i get the Ubuntu writing, followed by a black screen, this black screen sticks at this point prior to the login screen, if i press 'Ctrl + Alt + Del' the Ubuntu logo re-appears and my computer shuts down. I have re-installed Ubuntu several times as a dual boot with windows 7. This problem persists, Please advise, from my research it looks like a configuration issue with the graphics card, however i have found no sure answer.

Please Advise me on this

Answer (score -1):

Im not really sure. But something like this usually happens when your ubuntu.iso (image file) or dvd is corrupted/broken. Have you tried download n use another new ubuntu dvd/iso? 
Make sure to download directly from the official website n get specified version for your pc